# How are the attribute names on objects stored in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory

I was always under the assumption that the keys of an object were stored as strings, and that any non-string value would be cast. So, it was under this assumption, while writing some code that had to store a small value for many thousands of keys, I converted all the keys to base 36:

```
// theKey is an integer
myMap[theKey.toString(36)] = theValue;
```

Then, I decided to see whether my assumption was actually correct, and used Chrome's profiler to check the memory usage. Roughly here are the tests I ran and the memory usage:

```
window.objIntegers = {};
for (i = 100000; i--) window.objIntegers[i] = 'a';
// 786kb

window.objStrings = {};
for (i = 100000; i--) window.objStrings[i.toString(36)] = 'a';
// 16.7mb!

// and the same pattern but with:
key = i + .5;  // 16.7mb
key = i + '';  // 786kb
key = '0' + i; // 16.7mb
key = i + '0'; // 16.7mb
```

Obviously, my assumptions were off. What I'm wondering though, is how they are being stored and whether this behaviour is standard, or just some extra trickery which has been added by the Chromium/WebKit team?

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed some extra trickery by V8.

A `JSObject` (internal C++ representation of a JS `Object`) has two attributes, `elements` and `properties`, where the "elements" are JS attributes with numerical indices, while the "properties" are JS attributes with string indices.

Obviously, numerical indices consume far less memory here, since the property names need not be stored.

http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/chrome/devtools/docs/memory-analysis-101.html#primitive_objects

> A typical JavaScript object posesses two arrays: one for storing named properties, another for storing numeric elements.

This can be seen from v8 source code:

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/objects.h#1483

```
// [properties]: Backing storage for properties.
...
// [elements]: The elements (properties with names that are integers).
```

http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/runtime.cc#4462

```
MaybeObject* Runtime::SetObjectProperty(Isolate* isolate,
                                        Handle<Object> object,
                                        Handle<Object> key,
                                        Handle<Object> value,
                                        PropertyAttributes attr,
                                        StrictModeFlag strict_mode) {
  ...

  // Check if the given key is an array index.
  uint32_t index;
  if (key->ToArrayIndex(&index)) {
    // In Firefox/SpiderMonkey, Safari and Opera you can access the characters
    // of a string using [] notation.  We need to support this too in
    // JavaScript.
    // In the case of a String object we just need to redirect the assignment to
    // the underlying string if the index is in range.  Since the underlying
    // string does nothing with the assignment then we can ignore such
    // assignments.
    if (js_object->IsStringObjectWithCharacterAt(index)) {
      return *value;
    }

    Handle<Object> result = JSObject::SetElement(
        js_object, index, value, attr, strict_mode, set_mode);
    if (result.is_null()) return Failure::Exception();
    return *value;
  }

  if (key->IsString()) {
    Handle<Object> result;
    if (Handle<String>::cast(key)->AsArrayIndex(&index)) {
      result = JSObject::SetElement(
          js_object, index, value, attr, strict_mode, set_mode);
    } else {
      Handle<String> key_string = Handle<String>::cast(key);
      key_string->TryFlatten();
      result = JSReceiver::SetProperty(
          js_object, key_string, value, attr, strict_mode);
    }
    if (result.is_null()) return Failure::Exception();
    return *value;
  }

  // Call-back into JavaScript to convert the key to a string.
  bool has_pending_exception = false;
  Handle<Object> converted = Execution::ToString(key, &has_pending_exception);
  if (has_pending_exception) return Failure::Exception();
  Handle<String> name = Handle<String>::cast(converted);

  if (name->AsArrayIndex(&index)) {
    return js_object->SetElement(
        index, *value, attr, strict_mode, true, set_mode);
  } else {
    return js_object->SetProperty(*name, *value, attr, strict_mode);
  }
}
```

I won't go into the details, but note that `SetObjectProperty` calls either `SetElement` or `SetProperty`, depending on the key. Not sure why the check fails in your test case `key = i + '0'` though.

Answer (score 0):

It's optimizations in Chromium. I believe it has heuristics ([here's one mention of it](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164#c111)) to determine the most efficient way to store properties internally. All that the ECMAScript spec dictates is the interface between JavaScript and the environment and says nothing about how the objects exposed to JavaScript are implemented internally.